# Best CSS Grid - 2011

Tags: css, css-frameworks

I know this was asked before, but the other question was a couple of years old - and as fast as technology progresses....

We're looking at redesigning a website that was last designed in 2004.  I've been using the 960 grid and am preferential to it, but was wondering what everyone else's opinion was on this.  What about the [1140 Grid](http://cssgrid.net/)?

The site is for a local government site so there will be a wide range of users/browsers accessing it.

Comment: Please link to the question you're referring to.

Answer (score 0):

**Use media queries to serve a optimized grid that fit device type**

Recommend providers of optimized grid:

**978.gs**: http://978.gs/

On this site you find grids optimized for several screen sizes. It is optimized for mobile(300), tablet(748), web(978 and 1218) and big screens(1378).
See demo page to see how ity work in screen resolutions.

**Less**: http://lessframework.com/

Every layout in Less Framework is based on a single grid, composed of 68 px columns with 24 px gutters. The only measures that change from layout to layout are the amount of columns and the width of the outer margins.